# My app keeps on crashing

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple app with a relative layout containing three buttons but it keeps on crashing when I launch it in the emulator.

**my layout xml is shown bellow:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/two"></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Unless you paste your crash message, we won't be able to help you

Comment: add your logcat please and check your manifest

Comment: in the emulator it says "appname keeps stopping"

Comment: Have you missed android:layout_width and android:layout_height for the buttons?

Comment: @userr, Kindly Edit your Question & Paste Error Log from Emulator same as you are receiving. Also, Refer [How to Ask Question Properly on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set width,height to button

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/two" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works

Comment: you're welcome :) pls accept answer

Answer (score 0):

Add  android:layout_width and android:layout_height for the buttons